# Angular live video from Websocket

Tags: angular, websocket, video-streaming

I'm currently using [jsmpeg package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmpeg) to display live video through Websocket in my Angular app, but this package seems pretty old and wasn't updated for a long time and misses some new features from an [original package](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg). Right now I'm thinking to switch to [jsmpeg player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmpeg-player) which supports newer version of jsmpeg, but maybe someone knew another options for displaying live video through websockets in Angular?
Thanks